# jQuery validating multiple input:file

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<input id="upload1" type="file" /><br/>
<input id="upload2" type="file" /><br/>
<input id="upload3" type="file" /><br/>
<input id="upload4" type="file" /><br/>
<input id="upload5" type="file" /><br/>
<span id="label" style="color:red; display:none">
Wrong filetype!
</span>
```

And the following jQuery:

```
$('input:file').change(function(){
    var ext = $(this).val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase();
    $('#label').toggle(ext != 'pdf');
});
```

What I want to do, is only toggle the `#label` if all 5 of the `input:file` elements pass the validation (pdf extension only). Or no file selected.

At the moment, if i select a `.jpg` first, the `#label` displays, then if i select a `.pdf` the `#label` disappears. This is incorrect as there is still a `.jpg` selected in one of the five `input:file` elements.

**EDIT**: Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/general_exception/nnZsA/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to change it to:

```
$('input:file').change(function(){
    var
        all_ok = true,
        inputs_set = $('input:file');

    for (var e in inputs_set) {
        if (e.val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase() != 'pdf') {
            all_ok = false;
        }
    }

    $('#label').toggle(!all_ok);
});
```

Comment: Managed to do it with a variation of this answer. However @Zathrus Writer is correct, a persistent variable needs to be used. Marking this as answered because of this.

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
$('input:file').change(function(){

    $('input:file').each(function(){
      var ext =   $(this).split('.').pop().toLowerCase();

        $('#label').toggle(ext != 'jpg');
    });
});​
```

Comment: this will hide the actual label if the very last file input is OK, it needs a persistent variable to check for OK value in **all** fields and react accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it with a combination of both answers:-

```
$('input:file').change(function() {  
    var allok = true;
    $('input:file').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() !== "" &&
            $(this).val().split('.').pop().toLowerCase() != 'pdf') {
                allok = false;
        }
    });
    $('#label').toggle(!allok);
});
```